# Specific java method return null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to specify whether an specific node is neighbor with set of nodes in defined graph or not? For this purpose i wrote this method:

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
        for(Customer customer:collection){
            if(network.isSuccessor(customer, node)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

unfortunately this method return null pointer exception. So i decided to change that to:

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
        Collection<Customer> nodes=network.getVertices();
        ArrayList<Customer> acctualNodes = new ArrayList<Customer>();
        Customer acctualNode=new Customer();
        for(Customer customer: collection){
            for(Customer cust:nodes){
                if(cust.getName().equals(customer.getName())) acctualNodes.add(cust);
            }
        }
        for(Customer customer: nodes){
            if(node.getName().equals(customer.getName())) acctualNode=customer;
        }
        for(Customer customer: acctualNodes){
            if(network.isSuccessor(customer, acctualNode)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The new method works fine but it takes huge resource and time and its useless. My question is **how can i handle null pointer exception in a way that the defined method takes less time for execution?**

I debugged my method. Here is the information about the three used objects:

```
collection: ArrayList<E> id=17
elementData Object[6246]  (id=37)   

node: Customer id=23
customerArray   null    
customerName    "9379090484" (id=1345)  
type    null    

network: DirectedSparseGraph<V,E> id=27
edge_type   EdgeType  (id=39)   
edges   HashMap<K,V>  (id=42)   
vertices    HashMap<K,V>  (id=47)   
entrySet    HashMap$EntrySet  (id=1349) 
hashSeed    -949367244  
keySet  HashMap$KeySet  (id=48) 
loadFactor  0.75    
modCount    64780   
size    64780   
table   HashMap$Entry<K,V>[131072]  (id=52) 
threshold   98304   
useAltHashing   false   
values  null
```

As you can see none of the specified objects are null! So what could caused the NPE?!

Comment: why does it throw null pointer exception ? what gets null ?

Comment: Your first approach looks like a better one, and you haven't explained the details of the NPE you're getting. Is the `network` field `null`? What does the `isSuccessor` method look like? Did somebody pass in a `null` collection or one with a `null` entry? (Also, when you're writing a method, you should be flexible in what you accept. You certainly can take any `List<Customer>`, and `Collection<Customer>` is probably fine.)

Comment: First off, when you get a NPE the exception trace will tell you exactly where.  Maybe you should tell us.  Second, maybe you should actually debug the thing to figure out which pointer is null.

Comment: I debug my method several times. Nothing was null, just the reference number of objects in network vertices are different from objects in node and collection!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you have two different instances of the same object in to different collections. Because of that you do search by name, these lines:

```
for(Customer customer: collection){
    for(Customer cust:nodes){
        if(cust.getName().equals(customer.getName())) acctualNodes.add(cust);
    }
}
```

and then use isSuccessor method for correct instances

If my assumtion is right then way you go is:

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
        HashMap<String, Customer> realNodes = new HashMap<String, Customer>();
        Collection<Customer> nodes=network.getVertices();

        for (Customer n: nodes) {
            realNodes.put(n.getName(), n);
        }

        Customer acctualNode = realNodes.get(node.getName());
        for(Customer customer:collection){
            Customer actualCustomer = realNodes.get(customer.getName());
            if(network.isSuccessor(actualCustomer, acctualNode)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

EDIT - Added notes:
This will work relatively fast, but I belive bottle neck in network object, getting all node doesn't look good for me. If there is an method which returns CustomerNode by a name then you need to use it instad of putting all objects in HashMap.

EDIT2 - Try make it faster.
I don't know the package you use but probably jung implementation of DirectSparseGraph if so. I found in sources of the jung an implementation of getSuccessor method:

```
public Collection<V>  getSuccessors(V vertex)
    {
        if (!containsVertex(vertex))
            return null;
        return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(getSuccs_internal(vertex));
    }
```

and there is no isSuccessor. I made assumption that your isSuccessor method throws NPE because getSuccessors method return null. It returns null because a passed vertex cannot be found. Vertexes in collection are comparing using equals method. Here is my purpousal: define equals method in Customer object and compare by name (better to define equals and hashCode methods together and generate them from IDE - Eclipse, IDEA, NetBeans):

```
public class Customer {
...
 private String name;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Customer other = (Customer ) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

After that you can try use your first approach. If it doesn't work then my assumption about isSuccessor method and NPE isn't right and you could try to define isSuccessor method your self:

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
        for(Customer customer:collection){
            //if(network.isSuccessor(customer, node)) { 
            if(isSuccessor(network, customer, node)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean isSuccessor(DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network, Customer customer, Customer node) {
        Customer mockNode = node;
        Customer mockCustomer = customer;
        // If you can't redefine equals method for Customer object then you need to create a mock object mockNode.equals(node) == true && mockCustomer.equals(customer)
        Collection<Customer> successors = network.getSuccessors(mockNode);
        return successors != null && successors.indexOf(mockCustomer) != -1;
    }
```

If you can't redefine equals method for Customer object then you need to create mock objects before pass them into network object, so the following condition should be true:

```
mockNode.equals(node) && mockCustomer.equals(customer)
```

But it would be better if you can define equals and hasCode methods I believe it will help you significantly.

Comment: It is really interesting, it is much faster than the verion i wrote. Is there any way to make it faster? It is part of a huge run and it would really help if i make this part the fastest.

Comment: WOW, your answer definitely need + vote, unfortunately i could not vote that because of reputation, Hop somebody do that for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but if it's "micro-optimisation" you need, perhaps this will help:

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
    if (network == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Network may not be null.");
    }

    if (collection == null) {
        return false;
    }

    for(Customer customer : collection){
        if(network.isSuccessor(customer, node)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before proceeding for neighbor analysis. Eg.

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node, DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
    if (null == collection || collection.size() == 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for (Customer customer : collection) {
            if (network.isSuccessor(customer, node)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Similarly you must have null check for all the arguments you have in your function to avoid NPE.

Comment: Actually the problem is caused by different objects. The specified objects that i sent to this method by calling it, are not network vertex per se. So adding this checking process will not help me, look at the second method that i wrote you will find out what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the following as well.

```
private boolean isNeighbor(ArrayList<Customer> collection, Customer node,DirectedSparseGraph<Customer, Transaction> network) throws SQLException {
    boolean isNeighbor = false;
    try {
        for(Customer customer:collection) {
            if (network.isSuccessor(customer, node)) {
                isNeighbor = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (NullPointerException npe) {
        npe.printStackTrace();
        isNeighbor = false;
    }

    return isNeighbor

}
```

Comment: This method always return false in my case.

Comment: It means something is always null.

Comment: @Alin And what does the stack trace say? On which line is the NPE?